# JSBin: How to create demo example's of sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, jsbin

I want share working live example of SAPUI5 on stackoverflow, but I don't know how to create the JSBin example or which things we have to add or is there any simple way to create demo example of JSBin.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) which is runnable by clicking the blue 'Run Code Snippet' button:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
onInit : function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({
        rows : [
            { value : "sap-icon://syringe",    col2 : "Value 2",  col3 : "Value 3",  ol4 : "Value 4" },
            { value : "sap-icon://account",    col2 : "Value 10", col3 : "Value 11", col4 : "Value 12" },
            { value : "sap-icon://chalkboard", col2 : "Value 14", col3 : "Value 15", col4 : "Value 16" },
            { value : "sap-icon://e-care",     col2 : "Value 18", col3 : "Value 19", col4 : "Value 20" }
        ]
    });

    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
}
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```css
/* extra CSS classes here */
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
<mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Table items="{/rows}">
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Col1" />
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Col2" />
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Col3" />
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <core:Icon src="{value}" />
                    <Text text="{col2}" />
                    <Text text="{col3}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</mvc:View>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur  time @Qualiture but I want to fix header also

Comment: ? Not sure what you mean? This is just an example how to create a demo example using Stackoverflow instead of JSBin

Answer (score 0):

You will need bootstrap script, `View` which will be in *HTML* tab only and its `Controller` under *Javascript* tab.

You can save [this](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output) as your template after logging in and use it as starting point for your expamples.