# Functionality on Breadcrumbs navigation

Tags: javascript, json, tree, sapui5, breadcrumbs

I am trying to extend the basic [tree](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Tree/code/Tree.json) example and add a breadcrumbs navigation on top.

**View**

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.m.sample.Tree.Page"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">
<Breadcrumbs id="bread" currentLocationText="{/sNode}">
</Breadcrumbs>
    <Tree
        id="Tree"
        items="{path: '/'}"
        toggleOpenState="onToggle">
        <StandardTreeItem id="item" title="{title}" type="Navigation" press="test"/>
    </Tree>
```

**Controller**

```
  onInit: function(evt) {
    // set explored app's demo model on this sample
    var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.m.sample.Tree", "/Tree.json"));
    var data = this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  },
  onToggle: function(oEvent) {
    var lItem = oEvent.getParameters().itemContext.sPath;
    var lItem2 = oEvent.getParameter("itemContext");
    var nodes = this.getView().getModel().getProperty(lItem);
    var sNode = this.getView().getModel().getProperty(lItem).title;
    var oBreadCrumbs = this.byId("bread");
    if (!(paths.includes(lItem))) {
      arr.push(sNode);
    } else {
      var index = arr.indexOf(sNode);
      paths.length = index + 1;
      arr.length = index + 1;
    }
    paths.push(lItem);
    oBreadCrumbs.removeAllLinks();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (i == arr.length - 1) {
        oBreadCrumbs.setCurrentLocationText(arr[i]);
      } else {
        var link = new sap.m.Link({
          text: arr[i],
          press: [this.tryOne, oBreadCrumbs]
        });
        oBreadCrumbs.addLink(link);
      }
    }
  },
  tryOne: function(oEvent) {
    var t = oEvent.getSource();
    var n = this.indexOfLink(t);
    this.removeAllLinks();
    this.setCurrentLocationText(arr[n]);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var li = new sap.m.Link({
        text: arr[i],
        press: ? ? ? ?
      });
      this.addLink(li);
    }
  },
```

So what I am doing now is when a node of the tree expanded, the title added to the breadcrumbs navigation as a Link. What I want now, is when a user presses a link on the breadcrumbs navigation, all the links after the pressed one, should be removed and the pressed one should be the current Location.

With the function `tryOne`, I am repeating the whole procedure by find the last clicked element, add it in an array, remove everything and finally attach again the array to the links control.

My problem is that this function is working properly only for the first time. After the second time it stops working. Any ideas please?

[image: for example here, if I click on link Node1-1-2, this should become the currentLocation and the links after that should be removed.]

Comment: your function uses variables coming from upper scope 'paths' & 'arr' making it hard to understand + when you say it works only the first time, what happens the second time ?

Comment: oh yes you are right. There two arrays are two empty arrays which are declared outside of the function. When the navigation is created for the first time, when a link is clicked, the program goes to tryOne function. The navigation is created again there. My problem is that I don;t know what should I rum when a link pressed from tryOne function (this is why I hjave the press:???)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use breadcrumbs with tree dynamically SAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951236/use-breadcrumbs-with-tree-dynamically-sapui)

Comment: No, here I am stuck ina totally different point. I have the breadcrumbs created dynamically, but the links are not working! I need when a link is pressed to remove all the links after that. And I am trying to do this, with the function tryOne.

Comment: Can you please paste this code into [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mekogo/6/edit?html,output) or a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807408/jsbin-how-to-create-demo-examples-of-sapui5) in the question itself, so I can run it and debug the issue?